# How to prevent the page from going back to the beginning when making any changes to the css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I make any changes to the css of my web page, it updates and automatically goes back to the beginning, how can I make the change be made and continue in the same position on the screen without it going back to the beginning?

I use the Live Server extension and VS Code's Autosave to make changes automatic.

Comment: I thought Live Server "hot" updates CSS (or at least, has a default-enabled option to)?

Comment: Most JavaScript frameworks ship with something called hot module reloading or HMR. This accomplishes what you are looking for, though I’m not sure what could be done in pure html css and js

Comment: As I remember it, Live Server does this. It injects a script that creates a websocket connection, and certain changes are relayed through that and hot updated instead of doing a full reload. But for some reason it is not doing it in those case.